# For each number $d$ dividing 12, list the a's with $1 \leq a < 13$ and $e_{13} (a) = d$

Tags: roots

For each number $d$ dividing 12, list the a's with $1 \leq a < 13$ and $e_{13} (a) = d$

Can some explain the method of solving this number theory problem. Giving me a hard time, thanks.

Comment: What is $e_{13}(a)$?

Comment: It must be the order of $a$ in $\Bbb Z_{13}^*$

Answer (score 0):

Take any $a\neq 1$, for example, $2$. Now compute the successive powers of $a$:
$$2,4,8,3,6,12,11,9,5,10,7,1$$
We have been lucky: $2$ is a primitive root, that is, the powers of $2$ span every element of $\Bbb Z_{13}$.

Now, what would be $e(4)=e(2^2)$? And $e(5)=e(2^9)?$

Comment: so $e(2^2) = 12^2$

Comment: can you do a couple more, I still dont get the gist, thank you.